# Read AS3953 NFC EEPROM when the chip is not supplied

Tags: embedded, android, nfc

I want to read/write [AS3953](http://ams.com/eng/Products/NFC-HF-RFID/NFC-HF-Interface-and-Sensor-Tags/AS3953) (NFC chip) through SPI (MSP430) and PCD (Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini).

No problem for the first part (through MSP430 SPI). but when I want to read EEPROM values trough PCD, I have just a "bip" from my smartphone and the applications I use(NFC tag info, Nfc reader, ....) cannot read the tag.

The same behaviour with the constructor demokit.

Am I missing something to perform PCD-EEPROM read write ? [Datasheet](http://ams.com/eng/Products/NFC-HF-RFID/NFC-HF-Interface-and-Sensor-Tags/AS3953)

Actual Configuration word is: 7b 48 04 1c

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a similar situation (AS3953, ATtiny85, SPI) and asked AMS for support.
They suggested to use transparent mode (26 13 08 00 as the configuration word) and a phone should be able to read it.
My phone does not.
And my reading of the datasheet would make 26 13 18 00 transparent mode.

Anyway, this might work for you...give it a try.

Comment: I asked AMS for support to but they said that the chip is not ISO14443 compliant.
Dear Sir,

 

We have well received your request and we thank you.

You will find below the answer to your question.

 

 

Indeed, it is not feasible to R/W the EEPROM of AS3953 in passive mode by using a mobile phone.

 

For R/W wireless communication  with the EE of AS3953 it is indeed needed a proprietary protocol, which is feasible with a Reader but not with a mobile phone;

the AS3911-DK-ST Demo kit implements this proprietary protocol